# MinMaxScaler broadcast shapes

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, feature-scaling

I use a neural network with 3 inputs and 1 output with Keras. I'm using MinMaxScaler from sklearn to normalize my inputs in the range [0,1]

my input shape is (XX,3)
my output shape is (XX,1)

I don't have any input while scaling the input and output arrays

```
    self.scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

    dataX = self.scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
    dataY = self.scaler.fit_transform(dataY)

    self.model.fit(dataX,dataY,nb_epoch=1000)
```

After the training I have able to make prediction like this :

```
    data    = numpy.array([[ val1,val2,val3]])
    data = self.scaler.fit_transform(data)
    prediction = self.model.predict(data)
```

but my output is not scaled correctly, it make sense, as I didn't call inverse transform to apply the inverse scaling

but when I call it, I get a ValueError , I tried to apply the transformation on a single prediction or on an array of prediction but the problem is the same

```
self.scaler.inverse_transform(predictions) # prediction shape is (18,) :
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (3,) (18,)

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (18,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (18,3)

I undestand it is a shape issue, but the error message does not help so much

(12,1) was accepted by fit_transform (18,1) seems pretty similar.. so I dont get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made some mistakes on `MinMaxScaler`.

`MinMaxScaler` shouldn't be fitted twice(as internal parameters inside `MinMaxScaler` will be changed), and `dataX` & `dataY` should have their own scaler(as they have different minimum and maximum values.

Try to do something like this:

```
self.x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
self.y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

dataX = self.x_scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
dataY = self.y_scaler.fit_transform(dataY)

self.model.fit(dataX, dataY, nb_epoch=1000)

data = numpy.array([[val1, val2, val3]])
data = self.x_scaler.transform(data)
prediction = self.model.predict(data)
real_prediction = self.y_scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)
```